# Access C global variable 'errno' from C#

Tags: c#, c, mono, pinvoke, errno

Is it possible to access the "errno" variable in C# when P/Invoking? This is similar to Win32 GetLastError().

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm fairly sure that there is a way, but it probably is a bad idea. How would you guarantee that the runtime has not called some CRT function during its internal processing that has affected the `errno`?

For the same reason, you should not call `GetLastError` directly either. The `DllImportAttribute` provides a `SetLastError` property so the runtime knows to immediately capture the last error and store it in a place that the managed code can read using `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error`.

I think the most robust thing you could do in this case is make a C DLL that performs both the actual C work and the capture of the `errno`. (Note that just writing a wrapper around the `errno` capture would still have the concerns mentioned above.)

Comment: Yeah, I would agree with this.  It would probably be better to set a C wrapper a target function that would in turn return the value of errno from that.

Answer (score 4):

The solution is to use `SetLastError` on `DllImport`.  This will make the runtime save the last error so it can be accessed from `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error`.

There are two problems with calling `GetLastError` directly:

- The runtime might do sometime after the PInvoke returns before you are able to get the last error
- Multiple .NET threads can reside on the same native thread.  This can result in 2 .NET threads doing PInvokes, native libraries not knowing any better, would then overwrite the last error.  So thread A in .NET getting thread B's last error (potentially).

Comment: Can you show an example of the syntax for using `SetLastError` on `DllImport`?

Comment: @CraigMcQueen `[DllImport(LIB, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl, SetLastError=true)]` but this only works in `dotnet-sdk-5.0` but not with Mono ☹

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible - `GetLastError` does exactly that. However, as binarycoder pointed out, you should not do this directly - instead, set `SetLastError` on your `DllImport` to have this performed and cached automatically (and to avoid multithreading problems or runtime-invoked functions modifying the `errno` value) - then, on invoking the P/Invoked function, check it's return status, and if it's showing an error condition - throw `Win32Exception`, which reads the value of last error automatically. Yes, even on Mono on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, it is possible. 
At first, errno seems like magic.
But all magic is based on deception, and so is errno. 
errno is not a variable, it's a preprocessor-define !

From the [FreeBSD man-page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=errno&sektion=2&manpath=freebsd-release-ports):

```
extern int* __error();
#define errno (* __error())
```

Looking into the sources on my KDE-Neon Linux:

```
extern int *__errno_location (void) __THROW __attribute_const__;
# define errno (*__errno_location ())
```

(/usr/include/errno.h)

So you can get it in C# like this:
(caution, I assume it works the same on Linux, and I have not yet tested if I have handled the pointer correctly)

```
namespace MonoReplacement
{


    class MonoSux
    {

        private const string LIBC = "libc";


        // [System.CLSCompliant(false)]
        [System.Flags]
        public enum AccessModes
            :int 
        {
            R_OK = 1,
            W_OK = 2,
            X_OK = 4,
            F_OK = 8
        }

        public enum Errno
            :int 
        {
            EPERM = 1,
            ENOENT = 2,
            ESRCH = 3,
            EINTR = 4,
            EIO = 5,
            ENXIO = 6,
            E2BIG = 7,
            ENOEXEC = 8,
            EBADF = 9,
            ECHILD = 10,
            EAGAIN = 11,
            EWOULDBLOCK = 11,
            ENOMEM = 12,
            EACCES = 13,
            EFAULT = 14,
            ENOTBLK = 15,
            EBUSY = 16,
            EEXIST = 17,
            EXDEV = 18,
            ENODEV = 19,
            ENOTDIR = 20,
            EISDIR = 21,
            EINVAL = 22,
            ENFILE = 23,
            EMFILE = 24,
            ENOTTY = 25,
            ETXTBSY = 26,
            EFBIG = 27,
            ENOSPC = 28,
            ESPIPE = 29,
            EROFS = 30,
            EMLINK = 31,
            EPIPE = 32,
            EDOM = 33,
            ERANGE = 34,
            EDEADLK = 35,
            EDEADLOCK = 35,
            ENAMETOOLONG = 36,
            ENOLCK = 37,
            ENOSYS = 38,
            ENOTEMPTY = 39,
            ELOOP = 40,
            ENOMSG = 42,
            EIDRM = 43,
            ECHRNG = 44,
            EL2NSYNC = 45,
            EL3HLT = 46,
            EL3RST = 47,
            ELNRNG = 48,
            EUNATCH = 49,
            ENOCSI = 50,
            EL2HLT = 51,
            EBADE = 52,
            EBADR = 53,
            EXFULL = 54,
            ENOANO = 55,
            EBADRQC = 56,
            EBADSLT = 57,
            EBFONT = 59,
            ENOSTR = 60,
            ENODATA = 61,
            ETIME = 62,
            ENOSR = 63,
            ENONET = 64,
            ENOPKG = 65,
            EREMOTE = 66,
            ENOLINK = 67,
            EADV = 68,
            ESRMNT = 69,
            ECOMM = 70,
            EPROTO = 71,
            EMULTIHOP = 72,
            EDOTDOT = 73,
            EBADMSG = 74,
            EOVERFLOW = 75,
            ENOTUNIQ = 76,
            EBADFD = 77,
            EREMCHG = 78,
            ELIBACC = 79,
            ELIBBAD = 80,
            ELIBSCN = 81,
            ELIBMAX = 82,
            ELIBEXEC = 83,
            EILSEQ = 84,
            ERESTART = 85,
            ESTRPIPE = 86,
            EUSERS = 87,
            ENOTSOCK = 88,
            EDESTADDRREQ = 89,
            EMSGSIZE = 90,
            EPROTOTYPE = 91,
            ENOPROTOOPT = 92,
            EPROTONOSUPPORT = 93,
            ESOCKTNOSUPPORT = 94,
            EOPNOTSUPP = 95,
            EPFNOSUPPORT = 96,
            EAFNOSUPPORT = 97,
            EADDRINUSE = 98,
            EADDRNOTAVAIL = 99,
            ENETDOWN = 100,
            ENETUNREACH = 101,
            ENETRESET = 102,
            ECONNABORTED = 103,
            ECONNRESET = 104,
            ENOBUFS = 105,
            EISCONN = 106,
            ENOTCONN = 107,
            ESHUTDOWN = 108,
            ETOOMANYREFS = 109,
            ETIMEDOUT = 110,
            ECONNREFUSED = 111,
            EHOSTDOWN = 112,
            EHOSTUNREACH = 113,
            EALREADY = 114,
            EINPROGRESS = 115,
            ESTALE = 116,
            EUCLEAN = 117,
            ENOTNAM = 118,
            ENAVAIL = 119,
            EISNAM = 120,
            EREMOTEIO = 121,
            EDQUOT = 122,
            ENOMEDIUM = 123,
            EMEDIUMTYPE = 124,
            ECANCELED = 125,
            ENOKEY = 126,
            EKEYEXPIRED = 127,
            EKEYREVOKED = 128,
            EKEYREJECTED = 129,
            EOWNERDEAD = 130,
            ENOTRECOVERABLE = 131,
            EPROCLIM = 1067,
            EBADRPC = 1072,
            ERPCMISMATCH = 1073,
            EPROGUNAVAIL = 1074,
            EPROGMISMATCH = 1075,
            EPROCUNAVAIL = 1076,
            EFTYPE = 1079,
            EAUTH = 1080,
            ENEEDAUTH = 1081,
            EPWROFF = 1082,
            EDEVERR = 1083,
            EBADEXEC = 1085,
            EBADARCH = 1086,
            ESHLIBVERS = 1087,
            EBADMACHO = 1088,
            ENOATTR = 1093,
            ENOPOLICY = 1103
        }


        // int access(const char *pathname, int mode);
        // https://linux.die.net/man/2/access
        [System.Security.SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport(LIBC, CallingConvention = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "access", SetLastError=true)]
#if USE_LPUTF8Str
        internal static extern int access([System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPUTF8Str)] string path, AccessModes mode);
#else
        internal static extern int access([System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.CustomMarshaler, MarshalTypeRef = typeof(libACL.Unix.FileNameMarshaler))] string path, AccessModes mode);
#endif


        // char *strerror(int errnum);
        // https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strerror.3.html
        [System.Security.SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport(LIBC, CallingConvention = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "strerror")]
        internal static extern string strerror(Errno errnum);


        [System.Security.SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport(LIBC, EntryPoint = "__errno_location", CallingConvention = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        internal static extern System.IntPtr __errno_location();
        




        /// <summary>
        /// access() checks whether the calling process can access the file pathname. If pathname is a symbolic link, it is dereferenced.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="pathmame"></param>
        /// <param name="mode"></param>
        /// <returns>On success (all requested permissions granted), zero is returned. On error (at least one bit in mode asked for a permission that is denied, or some other error occurred), -1 is returned, and errno is set appropriately.</returns>
        public static bool Access(string pathmame, AccessModes mode)
        {
            int ret = access(pathmame, mode);

            if (ret == -1)
            {
                // return null;
                System.Console.Error.WriteLine("Error on Access");

                // https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/Mono.Posix/Mono.Unix.Native/Stdlib.cs
                // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485648/access-c-global-variable-errno-from-c-sharp
                // Errno errno = error();
                System.IntPtr errorptr = __errno_location();
                Errno errno = (Errno)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReadInt32(errorptr);

                string message = strerror(errno);

                // throw ACLManagerException(Glib::locale_to_utf8(strerror(errno)));
                throw new System.InvalidOperationException(message);
            } // End if (ret == -1) 

            return ret == 0;
        } // End Function Access 


    }


}
```

**Note:**
As mentioned by Jason Kresowaty, getting the errorno this way is a bad idea, because the CLR might call functions in the meantime. 
But according to [developers.redhat.com](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2019/03/25/using-net-pinvoke-for-linux-system-functions/), you can use Marshal.GetLastWin32Error on Linux, too.

Example:

```
[DllImport("libc", SetLastError = true))]
public static extern int kill(int pid, int sig);
```

> SetLastError means the function uses errno to indicate what went
> wrong. Marshal.GetLastWin32Error can be used to retrieve errno.

This is also what [Tmds.LibC](https://github.com/tmds/Tmds.LibC) does (here, the property errorno replaces the magic preprocessor-define):

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Tmds.Linux
{
    public static partial class LibC
    {
        public static unsafe int errno
            // use the value captured by DllImport
            => Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
    }
}
```

So, to emulate this behaviour in C#, we use a property instead:

```
public static Errno errno
{
    get
    {
        // How would you guarantee that the runtime has not called some CRT function 
        // during its internal processing that has affected the errno?

        // For the same reason, you should not call GetLastError directly either. 
        // The DllImportAttribute provides a SetLastError property so the runtime knows 
        // to immediately capture the last error and store it in a place that the managed code 
        // can read using Marshal.GetLastWin32Error.

        // this work on Linux !
        // Marshal.GetLastWin32Error can be used to retrieve errno.
        return (Errno)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
    }
}

string message = strerror(errorno);
```